# GraphViz Node Organization

Tags: graphviz, dot

I am trying to organize the nodes to be in a specific way but no matter what I try, I just cannot do it. I am trying to get close to this:
[image]

I have many variations but here is what I have so far: https://gist.github.com/wpsmithtwc/3f82433d11b2e99cc65382bf231aa04c
(see [GraphViz fiddle](http://stamm-wilbrandt.de/GraphvizFiddle/1.0.1/?1518561518402#digraph%20video%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20graph%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23rankdir%3D%22TB%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rankdir%3D%22LR%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ordering%3D%22out%22%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20node%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shape%3D%22Mrecord%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3D%22filled%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20color%3D%22white%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3D%22black%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3D%22white%22%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20Z%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3D%22black%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3D%22%23CDE5FE%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22%7BZ%7D%22%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20Y%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3D%22black%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3D%22%23CDE5FE%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22%7BB%7D%22%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20MAIN%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shape%3D%22Mrecord%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20color%3D%22black%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3D%22black%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3D%22%23CDFECE%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22%7BMAIN%7D%22%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20P1%20-%3E%20P4%5Bdir%3D%22both%22%2Ccolor%3D%22%235D9EFC%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20P1%20-%3E%20P2%5Bdir%3D%22both%22%2Ccolor%3D%22%235D9EFC%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20P2%20-%3E%20P3%5Bdir%3D%22both%22%2Ccolor%3D%22%235D9EFC%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20P2%20-%3E%20U%5Bcolor%3D%22%235D9EFC%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20P2%20-%3E%20P3%5Bcolor%3D%22%235D9EFC%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20P3%20-%3E%20U%5Bcolor%3D%22%235D9EFC%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20P3%20-%3E%20V%5Bcolor%3D%22%235D9EFC%22%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20Ingest%0A%20%20%20%20subgraph%20cluster_ingest%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20graph%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rank%3D%22same%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%20%3D%20%22Ingest%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20labelloc%3D%22t%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20labeljust%3D%22l%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3D%22filled%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20color%3D%22%23f3f3f3%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3D%22filled%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3D%22white%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20A%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20weight%3D1%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3D%22%230B24FB%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22%7BA%7D%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20B%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20weight%3D2%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3D%22%231683FB%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22%7BB%7D%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20C%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3D%22%231683FB%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22%7BC%7D%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20D%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3D%22%230B24FB%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22%7BD%7D%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20E%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3D%22%230B24FB%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22%7BE%7D%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20F%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3D%22%230B24FB%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22%7BF%7D%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20G%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3D%22%230B24FB%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22%7BG%7D%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20H%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3D%22%230B24FB%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22%7BH%7D%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20I%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3D%22%231683FB%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22%7BI%7D%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20J%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3D%22%231683FB%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22%7BJ%7D%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20OnPrem%0A%20%20%20%20subgraph%20cluster_onprem%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20graph%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22OnPrem%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rank%3D%22same%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20labelloc%3D%22t%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20labeljust%3D%22l%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3D%22filled%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20color%3D%22%23f3f3f3%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3D%22filled%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bgcolor%3D%22white%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20color%3D%22black%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3D%22white%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3D%22black%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shape%3D%22Mrecord%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%3B%0A%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20M1%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22%7BM1%7D%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20M2%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22%7BM2%7D%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20M3%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22%7BM3%7D%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20M4%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22%7BM4%7D%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20M5%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22%7BM5%7D%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20M5%20-%3E%20M4%20-%3E%20M3%20-%3E%20M2%20-%3E%20M1%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20Output%0A%20%20%20%20subgraph%20cluster_output%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20graph%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%20%3D%20%22Output%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20labelloc%3D%22t%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20labeljust%3D%22l%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3D%22filled%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20color%3D%22%23f3f3f3%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3Dfilled%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3D%22white%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20R%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3D%22%231683FB%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22%7BR%7D%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20S%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3D%22%231683FB%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22%7BS%7D%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20T%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3D%22%230B24FB%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22%7BT%7D%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20U%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3D%22%230B24FB%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22%7BU%7D%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20V%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3D%22%230B24FB%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22%7BV%7D%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20W%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3D%22%230B24FB%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22%7BW%7D%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20Apps%0A%20%20%20%20subgraph%20cluster_apps%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20graph%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%20%3D%20%22Apps%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20labelloc%3D%22t%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20labeljust%3D%22l%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3D%22filled%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20color%3D%22%23f3f3f3%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20P1%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shape%3D%22Mrecord%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20color%3D%22black%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3D%22black%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3D%22%23CDFECE%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22%7BP1%7D%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20P4%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shape%3D%22Mrecord%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20color%3D%22black%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3D%22black%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3D%22%23CDFECE%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22%7BP4%7D%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20P2%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shape%3D%22Mrecord%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20color%3D%22black%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3D%22black%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3D%22%23CDFECE%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22%7BP2%7D%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20P3%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shape%3D%22Mrecord%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20color%3D%22black%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fontcolor%3D%22black%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%3D%22%23CDFECE%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22%7BP3%7D%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20D%20-%3E%20M1%0A%20%20%20%20E%20-%3E%20M2%0A%0A%20%20%20%20F%20-%3E%20M3%0A%20%20%20%20G%20-%3E%20M3%0A%20%20%20%20H%20-%3E%20M3%20-%3E%20W%0A%0A%20%20%20%20I%20-%3E%20M4%0A%20%20%20%20J%20-%3E%20M5%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%23A%20-%3E%20B%20%23%20This%20causes%20problems%20for%20GraphViz%3F%3F%0A%0A%20%20%20%20A%20-%3E%20MAIN%0A%20%20%20%20B%20-%3E%20MAIN%0A%20%20%20%20C%20-%3E%20MAIN%0A%20%20%20%20D%20-%3E%20MAIN%0A%20%20%20%20M1%20-%3E%20MAIN%0A%20%20%20%20M2%20-%3E%20MAIN%0A%0A%20%20%20%20MAIN%20-%3E%20Y%0A%20%20%20%20Y%20-%3E%20Z%0A%0A%20%20%20%20MAIN%20-%3E%20P1%5Bcolor%3D%22%235D9EFC%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20MAIN%20-%3E%20R%5Bcolor%3D%22%235D9EFC%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20MAIN%20-%3E%20S%5Bcolor%3D%22%235D9EFC%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20MAIN%20-%3E%20T%5Bcolor%3D%22%235D9EFC%22%5D%0A%0A%7D)).

Any suggestions?

Comment: The odd node sequencing seems to caused by a bug related to the rankdir attribute .  See  https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues/1953